# intReg in R Code 100

Tags: r, regression

I've been trying to use the intReg package in R, but I got this as a result:

```
> y <- cbind(dataH$lb, dataH$ub)
> fit.int <- intReg(y ~ logSpread + logdepthS + logdepthO + last + ret + volatility + loghiddenVolS + loghiddenVolO + loghft1S + loghft1O + hft2S + hft2O + hft3S + hft3O + preEarnings + postEarnings, data = dataH)  
> summary(fit.int)
Error in class(coefValues) <- c("coef.intReg", class(coefValues)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

> coef(fit.int)
Error in class(coefValues) <- c("coef.intReg", class(coefValues)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

> print(coef(fit.int))
Error in class(coefValues) <- c("coef.intReg", class(coefValues)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

> fit.int
Interval regression

BHHH maximisation, 0 iterations
Return code 100: Initial value out of range.

> print(coef(fit.int, boundaries = TRUE))
Error in class(coefValues) <- c("coef.intReg", class(coefValues)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: When you're using formula, put all the data in the same data.frame. Next time I suggest you make a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help. I'm trying to copy the example in the intReg package by having y outside of the data frame.

Comment: Try assigning it to your data.frame and try again. It's not that hard. `dataH$y <- y`. :)

Comment: The example works for me, even when I do `Kakadu$lb <- lb;
Kakadu$ub <- ub;m <- intReg(with(Kakadu, cbind(lb, ub)) ~ sex + log(income) + age + schooling + 
              recparks + jobs + lowrisk + wildlife + future + aboriginal + finben +
              mineparks + moreparks + gov +
              envcon + vparks + tvenv + major, data=Kakadu)`.

Comment: Yea, I also did try having it in the data frame, but it still didn't work.